# How much does having Indexing running on my Samsung SSD affect health vs. search speed?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, search-indexing

I used the Samsung Magician program to check my SSD and it recommends disabling Indexing b/c it generates a lot of random reads and writes.

But it seems like if I disable Indexing then *everytime* I do a search it'll read *every* file.
That *seems* worse than the way I'd presume that Indexing works: reading each file as it changes. .

So, what's the relative improvement in Health (lifespan) for disabling Indexing?

Comment: Reading a file doesn't introduce a write to the device.  SSDs only have limited writes.  SSDs are extremely fast.  So indexing will decrease the lifespan of the device.

Comment: @Ramhound, I see. So, it's the constant writing to update the index that is causing the shortened life span.

Comment: @Ramhound , so, if I could store the index on a regular HDD then that would not shorten the lifespan, right? (not sure if that's possible.

Comment: My previous comment wasn't correct so I deleted it.  [Yes, what you describe is indeed possible.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-advanced-indexing-options)